# Mariadb 10.2.32 doesn't have REPLICATE_REWRITE_DB that can be set dynamically

Tags: replication, mariadb

I want to replicate DB from source to destination with another name. Seems like Replication filters like REPLICATE_REWRITE_DB filter is not availably dynamically .

**Mariadb Version : 10.2.32 Focal**  (Source and Destination have same version)

```
MariaDB [DB]> show variables like '%replica%';
+----------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                    | Value     |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_replication_delay         | 0         |
| replicate_annotate_row_events    | OFF       |
| replicate_do_db                  |           |
| replicate_do_table               |           |
| replicate_events_marked_for_skip | REPLICATE |
| replicate_ignore_db              |           |
| replicate_ignore_table           |           |
| replicate_wild_do_table          |           |
| replicate_wild_ignore_table      |           |
| skip_parallel_replication        | OFF       |
| skip_replication                 | OFF       |
| wsrep_mysql_replication_bundle   | 0         |
| wsrep_replicate_myisam           | OFF       |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
```

Kindly let me know if any one have done rewrite replication dynamically.

Comment: See also https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This restriction was relaxed in 10.11.1 ([MDEV-15530](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15530)), which per the [test cases allows dynamic changing](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/2231/files#diff-748b32fc9552a2bfa85d118454e3dba18db0870a043d75e564ad5fc71e40e24e).